# In >&N, why is N treated as file descriptor instead of as file name (as the manual seems to say)?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am struggling with understanding IO redirection in bash. I have seen many examples like the following (which is literally taken from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082001/how-do-file-descriptors-work)):

```
exec 3<> /tmp/foo  #open fd 3.
echo "test" >&3
exec 3>&- #close fd 3.
```

I don't understand the second line. To be precise, I don't understand how its behavior is in accordance with the bash manual.

Obviously, in the second line, `>&3` should redirect `stdout` (and possibly `stderr` - I don't know) to file descriptor 3; everything else wouldn't make any sense.

But from the [current bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) (at the time of writing), section 3.6.4 (formatting mine):

> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be *redirected to the file **whose name is the expansion of word.***
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
> `&>word` and `>&word`

[ It then explains subtle differences between the first and the second format, but let's put this aside for a moment because it is not important for the question. ]

To my understanding this says that `>&3` redirects `stderr` and `stdout` to a file whose name is `3`, which is quite different from redirecting `stdout` (and possibly `stderr`) to file descriptor `3`.

Could anybody please explain what I am missing?

Comment: Carry on reading [a little further the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, it's precisely the bit you put aside that is most relevant (from the [GNU bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error)):

> **3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error**
>
> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard
> error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the file whose
> name is the expansion of word.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard
> error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When using the second form, word may not expand to a number or ‘-’. If it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating
> File Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

That final note is the most important bit, so I will repeat it here:

> When using the second form, word may not expand to a number or ‘-’. If it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating
> File Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

So if `word` expands to a number or `-`, special rules are triggered. Strings expand to themselves, so `3` can be said to "expand" to `3` which means that `>&3` is treated according to the rules described in the [Duplicating File Descriptors section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors):

> The redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]<&word
> ```
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors. If word expands
> to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be
> a copy of that file descriptor. If the digits in word do not specify a
> file descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs. If word
> evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n is closed. If n is not specified,
> the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.
>
> The operator
>
> ```
> [n]>&word
> ```
>
> is used similarly to duplicate output file descriptors. If n
> is not specified, the standard output (file descriptor 1) is used. If
> the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for output, a
> redirection error occurs. If word evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n
> is closed. As a special case, if n is omitted, and word does not
> expand to one or more digits or ‘-’, the standard output and standard
> error are redirected as described previously.

All this to say that in the *specific* case where what comes after the `>&` is a number, that number is assumed to be a file descriptor. Presumably, this is precisely why the manual states that `&>word` is preferred over the equivalent `>&word` since `&>word` is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot, +1 and accepted. That one really got me. Actually, I had stopped thinking about the part I had put aside (i.e. the difference between the two formats) when I head read the three words it ends with: "*for compatibility reasons*". Normally, I don't care about compatibility because `bash` in reasonably recent versions is the only shell I currently use, and thus, I usually don't put time in subjects that are tagged "compatibility". So I have learned an important lesson and will do this in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @Binarus, If I'm not mistaken, `>&` in the sense "redirect both stdout and stderr" is from csh, while `>&-` and `>&NN` are likely from some other Bourne-like shell (perhaps ksh), and they do conflict a bit. The latter ones are codified in POSIX (and they're much more useful in general, and can be used to compose the other meaning), so Bash has to give priority to them. I'm not sure about `&>`, it could be just a Bash-specific shorthand invented exactly because it doesn't clash that directly with the others. (It means something different but pretty much useless other shells)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you very much for that in-depth explanation!

Comment: @Binarus: You've now learned something: "for compatibility reasons" is a shorthand for "we think this behavior is inconsistent and/or stupid, but we can't change it because it was first implemented like this 40 years ago and now millions of programs depend on it."